# How to do count distinct with view query couchbase

Tags: couchbase

How would I count distinct values in couchbase with a view query?
Below is how to do it with N1QL.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT doc.id) FROM bucketName
[
   {
     "$1": 6234789987654
   }
]
```

My data set is huge so I don't want to run a N1QL query over it. I also do not want the row data as this would be huge as well and I am only interested in the count.

Answer (score 0):

## MAP

```
function (doc) {
    emit(doc.id, null)
}
```

## REDUCE

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  if (rereduce) {
    return values.length;
  } else {
    return values.length;
  }
}
```

And when you call the function group by the key ( ?group=true&rereduce=true )

Comment: I will say this however....having built an application on CouchDB...I would not do it again....

Comment: That gives me all the rows and the reduce gives me the count of documents containing that id. I want the count of unique ids

Comment: Can you post the output that you're getting?

Comment: If you decided to use N1QL check this out https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.1/performance/index_pushdowns.html#story-h2-10